# AC Measurements: Level Shifter vs Negative Voltage Supply

Tags: voltage-measurement

I’m trying to design a circuit capable of measuring AC signals with a high level of accuracy. The two most popular options I’ve seen so far are:

a) Supplying the ADC with a negative ground supply (2.5Vref, Vp=2.5V, Vn=-2.5V)

b) Using an op-amp to first divide, then shift the input voltage to be in the range of 0-2.5V.

If my main goal here is acccuracy while minimizing power consumption, which of these two options would be my best bet?

To be more specific:

AC signal between -2.5V and 2.5V (divided down from 0-1000Vp via a resistor network). Accuracy anywhere between millivolts and microvolts, frequency range from 0-100kHz, and I’m using the AD7768-4 combined with the LTC6269IMS8E-10#PBF op-amp.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information if you want an informed answer.  First "high level of accuracy" is not an engineering term. Exactly what accuracy are you trying to achieve? Second, what is the frequency range and level of your AC signals? Third, what ADC are you planning to use? I think ;you get the point by now.

Comment: Ahh ok fair point. AC signal between -2.5V and 2.5V (divided down from 0-1000Vp via a resistor network). Accuracy anywhere between millivolts and microvolts, frequency range from 0-400kHz, and I’m using the AD7768-4 combined with the LTC6269IMS8E-10#PBF op-amp.

Comment: *100kHz, not 400kHz

Comment: Do you mean accuracy? (Which means periodic recalibration against NIST or DIN standard references.) Or do you mean precision? And, to go yet another step, do you mean repeatable precision across multiple instruments built without calibration and just stuffed with parts, the precision being the allowable variations between one and any of a thousand other devices built and uncalibrated? This can get very interesting depending on how you respond.

Comment: Does it matter? Lol. Holding up accuracy over time implies precision. Just trying to figure out, in general, which is more standard: shifting an input voltage so it can be read with a 0-5V ADC, or sampling the whole wave with -2.5<V<2.5